# Smart Wizard ToolbarButtonPosition : 'right' not working

Tags: jquery, smart-wizard

I am using smart wizard 2 . I have the wizard showing up correctly however one thing does not work. The toolbarButtonPosition always shows up on left side even if i give it the value of right. This is what i have

```
toolbarSettings: {
                toolbarPosition: 'both', // none, top, bottom, both
                toolbarButtonPosition: 'right', // left, right
                showNextButton: true, // show/hide a Next button
                showPreviousButton: true, // show/hide a Previous button
                toolbarExtraButtons: [
            $('<button></button>').text('Finish')
                          .addClass('btn btn-info')
                          .on('click', function(){ 
                        alert('Finsih button click');                            
                          }),
            $('<button></button>').text('Cancel')
                          .addClass('btn btn-danger')
                          .on('click', function(){ 
                        alert('Cancel button click');                            
                          })
                      ]
            },
```

The toolbar position does take effect but the button position always remains on the left no matter what i do. I cant seem to find anything over the net and i cant seem to figure what the issue might be.

Does anyone else had this issue? Can this not be fixed?